# User registration using ASP.NET Identity v3 - users and database are not created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I am trying to build a simple login system from the ground up, using ASP.NET MVC v5, Entity Framework v7, and Identity v3.

All I want is for the user to create an account, and for that account to be saved in a database. I was able to get it working with Identity v2, and the scaffolded MVC app uses Identity v3 to create a database and save users just fine, so I'm trying to connect the code from both working apps to make a new one.

Here's the code I have so far:

*Startup.cs*:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

*appsettings.json* contains this code for the connection to the database:

```
"Data": {
  "DefaultConnection": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SimpleAuthenticationApp;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Here's the code for the Register POST action in *Controllers/AccountController.cs*:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register (RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            return View("Home", "Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Here, I set a break point at the try block, and when it enters the catch block, the exceptions reads "Count=1", or "One or more errors occurred", and I'm not sure how to see what those errors are.

In this code, `RegisterViewModel` is just a ViewModel with fields for Email, Password, and ConfirmPassword.
The *Account/Register* view is just a form that asks for these fields. `ApplicationUser` is a class that extends from `IdentityUser`.

I'm stuck here, and I'd like to figure out how to get the app to create a database and save user profiles in it using Identity. Any ideas for the code, or how to see what the error messages are?

Comment: To figure out what error has occurred see InnerException property of catched Exception.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The InnerException here just says "One or more errors occurred", is there any way to see what those errors are?

Comment: InnerException has nested InnerExceptions,  dig there :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to figure out how to get the app to create a database and save user profiles in it using Identity.

As far I know database is not created automatically during user registration process, so you need have updated db before.

You can create db yourself or you can use [DB initializers](https://www.bing.com/search?q=EF%20DB%20Initializers).

Remember - if you use Code-First approach - that you need apply all migrations before lunching app

Console command in VS2015 RC1: `dnx ef database update`

> All I want is for the user to create an account, and for that account to be saved in a database. I was able to get it working with Identity v2, and the scaffolded MVC app uses Identity v3 to create a database and save users just fine, so I'm trying to connect the code from both working apps to make a new one.

Maybe starting form latest code will be better way then connecting old and new ? Try create new Project with default implementation - it's works fine for me, and then you can extend default solution as you want :)

More about [Authentication](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/index.html) and [Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html).

> Here, I set a break point at the try block, and when it enters the catch block, the exceptions reads "Count=1", or "One or more errors occurred", and I'm not sure how to see what those errors are.

Use `ex.ToString()` method - this give you full stack information about exception and all inner exceptions.